# Adding data-theme to all items

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, data-theme

How can I add the `data-theme` value to all divs, listviews, forms, li, ul etc. from JavaScript?
Is it possible? If yes how can I do that?

Will something like the following work?

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme= "e";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function (el) {
    el.setAttribute("data-theme", "e");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have jquery-mobile included, following should work:

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme= "e";
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme= "e";
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme= "e";
```

However if you added any elements that are not part of header, content or footer, then you should go with Domenic's way of applying for every element

Comment: This looks better than my version, I'd think... It comes from someone who actually knows jQuery mobile :)